# Microsoft Fakes doesnt generate fake for methods returning certificates

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to shim a class which has methods to return certificates. In the below example class, I see that GetResult() gets a shim method under ShimClass1. But, there are no shims created for methods that return a certificate. Any idea how I would shim a method that return certs?

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static bool GetResult() // Shim available
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static void GetCertificate1(out X509Certificate2 cert) // Shim un-available
    {
        cert = null;
    }

    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate2() // Shim un-available
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using VS2015?  Do you have .NET 4.6 installed on your machine?  What version .NET is the test project targeting?

Comment: I have VS 2015 and .Net 4.6.

Comment: Is your project targeting .NET 4.6 or .NET 4.5.2? [This Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1573824/can-not-generate-fakes-methods-that-have-parameters-of-type-x509certificate2) states that if you have .NET 4.6 installed and are targeting 4.5.2 in your test project, you won't be able to generate fakes for methods that return an X509Certificate2.

Comment: I have a similar situation here; my test project targets net461 (same as the project under test), and Fakes does not generate a shim for the `X509Certificate2` class. All other types of the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`-namespace are present, I would say. I use Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2012 R2, and I have fake-assembly references for both `System.dll` and `mscorlib`. Since Connect is retired by today, I would be glad if somebody has information regards this particular issue...